# Extract capture group names from a regular expression string in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a quick way to extract the capture group names out of any regular expression string in Java.
If possible, a regular expression that parses other regular expressions would be a solution, otherwise a "quick and dirty" but proven to work parser would also be a solution.
If possible I would like to avoid external libraries/dependencies.

For example given the input:

```
/(?<name>\w+) (?<surname>\w+)/gm
```

The expected output is an array/list/set of 2 strings :

```
String[] output = new String[]{"name", "surname"};
```

I tried to use reflection to no avail.
When debugging, a Pattern object contains a namedGroups field which contains the information I want, it is a Map and I'm only interested in the KeySet.

I would write a parser myself, but I can't find a Java regex syntax document.

```
package my.package;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j // lombok declares slf4j static log variable
public class MyPatternUtils {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static final Map<String, Integer> getNamedGroups(Pattern pattern) {
        if (pattern == null) {
            return Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(2));
        }

        // Cannot place class in java.util.regex package due to security exceptions
        // accessing methods with default access modifiers (compiles, but returns security exception on class loading)
//        try {
//            return Collections.unmodifiableMap(pattern.namedGroups());
//        } catch (Throwable t) {
//
//        }
//
//        try {
//            Map<String, Integer> namedGroups = pattern.namedGroups;
//            if (namedGroups == null) {
//                namedGroups = new HashMap<>(2);
//            }
//            return Collections.unmodifiableMap(namedGroups);
//        } catch (Throwable t) {
//
//        }

        try {
            Class<Pattern> patternClass      = Pattern.class;
            Method         namedGroupsMethod = patternClass.getMethod("namedGroups", new Class<?>[] {});
            namedGroupsMethod.setAccessible(true);
            Object namedGroupsObject = namedGroupsMethod.invoke(pattern, new Object[] {});
            return Collections.unmodifiableMap((Map<String, Integer>) namedGroupsObject);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log.error("err", t); // no such method
        }

        try {
            Class<Pattern> patternClass     = Pattern.class;
            Field          namedGroupsField = patternClass.getField("namedGroups");
            namedGroupsField.setAccessible(true);
            Object namedGroupsObject = namedGroupsField.get(pattern);
            if (namedGroupsObject == null) {
                namedGroupsObject = (Object) new HashMap<String, Integer>(2);
            }
            return Collections.unmodifiableMap((Map<String, Integer>) namedGroupsObject);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log.error("err", t); // no such field
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(2));
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't realy get what is going on in your `MyPatternUtils` class. But if all you need is the group names in an array, shouldn't something like `String[] res = Pattern.compile("\\?<(\\w+)\\>").matcher(regex).results().map(mr -> mr.group(1)).toArray(String[]::new);` enough?

Comment: Well yes, but there are other ways to express groups such as `/(?P<name>Sally)/`. The question then becomes : if I list all the possible ways to name groups, is this method guaranteed to work (and match capture group names) on all possible regular expressions ? And if so, how can it be proven ?

Comment: _"I can't find a Java regex syntax document"_ Have you looked at the [javadoc of `java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Comment: Yes, but although rather complete, that is 'usage' documentation I'm not sure It can be used as reference for a `parser implementation`. The documentation states in fact that is is a summary, it also references PERL 5, and a book from 2006 which also is neither technical nor a specification or reference manual, but rather a generic and perhaps in depth guide on regular expressions in general.